# TokenMismatchException in Laravel : Unable to login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, token

Getting TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken while trying to login. Could see cookies are not getting created. What could be the possible cause?

Below are the observations:

1) Have added:

```
 < input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

but still the issue remains.

2) Have changed in sessions.php from :

```
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

to

```
 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'cookie'),
```

but still the issue remains.

3) I have tried with all the browsers, still no luck.

4) Same code base is working properly on other systems, but not on my system. Also  I have also re-installed windows, but still the same issue.

Please help

```
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 D:\Development\Code\biz\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 D:\Development\Code\biz\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 D:\Development\Code\biz\server.php(21): require_once('D:\\Development\\...')
#23 {main}
```

---

.env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=fbq7vdvBI18IzYMLDxi9fmvSUaXuxaNg

APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/Kolkata

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=tnpdb
DB_USERNAME=*********
DB_PASSWORD=*********
DB_STRICT=true
DB_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=******.*******************.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*******@******.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=*******@*******.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=*********

WKHTMLTOPDF_BIN=/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
WKHTMLTOIMG_BIN=/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage
```

---

sessions.php

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 15,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => null,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('HTTPS_ONLY_COOKIES', false),

];
```

---

VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    '*****response',
    '*****response',
    '*****response',
    'v1/*',
    ];
}
```

Comment: show us your .env and your session.php config file

Comment: try to change the session driver to cookie and test

Comment: then we have to see the controller and the form

Answer (score 0):

okey you should make your routes inside the web middleware like this :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
        Route::get('/','example@exemple');
    });
```

because sessions and token middlewares are in the same middleware group 'WEB' like that :

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

        ],
    ];
```

Comment: We are having laravel 5.1. Getting this error when we put the above code: "ReflectionException in Container.php line 741:
Class web does not exist"

Comment: can you give me your controller's name ?